# setting padding based on screen size with maximum padding

Tags: css, padding

I have a div that needs padding. I want the padding to decrease for small screens and the only way I could come up with is using media queries, but are there simpler solutions? If I use % or vw the padding gets too small on small screens (or too large on large screens).

Comment: Since what you want to create is unknown, it's rather difficult to say anything. Percentage as a unit of measurement is the best solution for your problem, but if you're not satisfied, show us what you have tried and try to give more details about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear so please specify if this is not your requested answer.

I'm assuming you are making a webpage and would like to have a bit of free space on the sides with big screens. But this space would need to be gone with smaller devices such as phones.

Most websites use a 'container' div to set a maximal width (mostly 1080px). So this means that on larger screens your content will have a bit of white space on the sides.

On smaller screens however your container will take up the whole screen, which is needed for smaller devices.

A code example:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1080px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.container>div {
  background: red;
  padding-left: 64px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <h1>My header</h1>
    <div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sorry my question seemed unclear. I have a div that has a background color and I have a table inside it. I néed the table to have some padding so that it doesn't go straight from edge to edge of the div around it. But I would like this padding to be a bit smaller on smaller screens because othterwise the table would get cut off, and I was wondering if there are any other ways then using media queries.